# Any example of Sending apprequest app-to-user?

Tags: facebook, api, sdk, apprequests

How can I send apprequest (app-to-user)? Do I need a special permission for that or just the user id? Any limitation of # of users per request? Anyone got sample code for sale?

```
I have already checked these links:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#apprequests
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think app-to-user requests are going to get you what you want. As they can only be sent to current app users.

From: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/

> **App To User Requests**
>
> App to User Requests can be used to re-engage a user in your app and
> can only be sent to users that have installed the app. For example,
> notifying a user that something has changed since their last visit,
> "10 of your friends are now online".
>
> App to User Request are sent via the Graph API, for more information
> see the apprequests docs. App to User Requests are only available for
> Canvas apps, not websites, as accepting a request will direct the user
> to the Canvas Page URL of the app that sent the Request. Notifying
> Users of a App Request
>
> App to User Requests do not create notifications, though they do
> appear in the App and Games Dashboard and increment an app bookmark
> counter, similar to User to User Requests. Accepting an App Request
>
> This process is identical to accepting a User to User Request.

From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#apprequests

> **Create**
>
> You can post a apprequest for a user by issuing an HTTP POST request
> to /USER_ID/apprequests with the app access_token.
>
> Note: POSTing to the Graph API endpoint of /USER_ID/apprequests is
> considered an App to User Request. App-Generated Requests do not
> receive notifications and get limited distribution in comparison to
> User to User Requests sent with the Request Dialog

Comment: Thanks for the tip of only available to Canvas apps.

Comment: **UPDATE:** App to User Request is now able to send to friends that does not install the game; and a non-friend but with the game installed. The link content is updated: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/requests/