# Posting automatic updates on a Facebook Page as Page not user

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, restfb

I posted yesterday a question about  [Posting app-generated comments on Facebook page using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874914/posting-app-generated-comments-on-facebook-page-using-java) but from the answer i got i realized i to a point that its probably not the question i needed to ask. What i want to achieve is the following:

I have a Facebook Page that represents a product. I cant get in to specifics of what it is but i can present a made up scenario that relates to my problem. Lets say that product was a restaurant and i have a web page for it. So i want to link my Facebook page(for that restaurant) and the web page i crated. On my web page i have the following functionality. Every week one of my services picks 5 menus and makes them promotional and displays them on the home page. Now i want those 5 menus to be posted on the Facebook page i created for the restaurant automatically. Meaning no one will administer this posting it will be done by the web application it self. Because is automated i don't want to prompt anyone to log in to Facebook every time this happens.

First of all can this be achieved? or there are some restriction from facebook that disallow this action.

If yes can someone point me to an example in Java where this is done.

So far i created an app on Facebook so that up has a page for it self. But when i did the actions i pointed out in [Posting app-generated comments on Facebook page using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874914/posting-app-generated-comments-on-facebook-page-using-java) the post was not displayed. I managed to post from my app to my profile saying that the post was done through my app but this is not what i am looking for.

If all of this can be achived, can it be done with RestFb as an API?